# How to set form input values using jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, focus, using

I am trying to give the form input a default value which changes when the user clicks on the input box.

How can I do this using jquery?

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('#tradition').click(function() {
$('#form-container').attr("class","trade");                         
$('.lblMadlib11').text("Eleven ");


$('.lblMadlib11a').val("eleven value field");


             });
```

Ho can I use / add focus to the existing code for the field called "lblMadlib11a" on focus to remove the default value.

Answer (score 2):

suppose you have an input text like this:

```
<input id="username" type="text" value="insert your username">
```

You could set empty value in this way

```
$('#username').focus(function() {
  this.value="";
});
```

Comment: how can i use this focus on the above code to reset value of "lblMadlib11a on focus? thanks

Comment: if lblMadlib11a is the input's name then you could try $('input[name="lblMadlib11a"]').focus(function() {
  this.value="";
});

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#inputbox').click(function() {

      this.attr('value', 'my new value')

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#sometextid").bind('click',function(){
            $(this).attr('value',"somevalue");
    })
```